# Array not incrementing

Tags: c++

I think know the problem is in one of the array functions and I just cannot see this error. I'm a beginner in c++, so there probably is some obvious error in here that someone might see. The compiler doesn't give me an error, it prints out the name and MPAA rating correctly and for the user rating it gives me 0.

Comment: Well, you definitely have a problem with your keyboard. It's TAB key appears to be broken, and not working. As a result, the unindented code is mostly unintelligible. You should, as the first order of business, get the keyboard fixed, and logically indent your code.

Comment: .. And the letters making up `const` seem not to be working as well

Comment: In the non-default constructor you don't initialize the `scoreRating` array. That leaves the contents *indeterminate* leading to *undefined behavior* when you use the array elements.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In the compiler it's much easier to read, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You are performing integer division here

```
return ((scoreRating[0] + scoreRating[1] + scoreRating[2] + scoreRating[3] + scoreRating[4]) / 5);
```

You need to perform floating point division, you can do this by changing at least one of the types (the literal `5.0` in this case) to a `double`

```
 return ((scoreRating[0] + scoreRating[1] + scoreRating[2] + scoreRating[3] + scoreRating[4]) / 5.0);
```

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid now, THANK YOU!